# ImageView not resizing image

Tags: imageview, javafx-2

I want to use an ImageView to resize an image, however the image is not being resized:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setFitHeight(40);
System.out.println("imageview image width = " + imageView.getImage().getWidth());
System.out.println("imageview image height = " + imageView.getImage().getHeight());
```

The output is

```
imageview image width = 674.0
imageview image height = 888.0
```

However, the width should be 40. My ImageView is not attached to any scene and I also don't want to attach it, it shall only be used for image resizing. **Is there any way to force the ImageView to resize its image, even though the ImageView is not attached to any scene?** The reason I am using an ImageView for resizing is, that I want to resize an Image in RAM, without reading it again from the disk, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911077/resize-an-image-without-reading-it-again-from-disk/14917551) for more details.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You are changing the size of the ImageView, but reading the size of the Image, try `imageView.getFitHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

Using an ImageView for resizing seems to be very hacky.

A better approach is to convert your Image into a BufferedImage and do the resizing the old way. (JavaFx does not (yet) provide an internal way to resize memory images)

```
int width = 500; // desired size
int height = 400;
Image original = ...; // fx image

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
        (int)original.getWidth(),
        (int)original.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(original, img);
BufferedImage rescaled = Scalr.rescaleImage(img, width, heigth);  // the actual rescale

// convert back to FX image
WritableImage rescaledFX = new WritableImage(width, heigth);
SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(rescaled, rescaledFX);
```

Where as [Scalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library) is a nice library for resizing images in native java. Obviously, you can use other/simpler methods of rescaling, but the image quality won't be that nice.